# Why doesn't Safari decodeURIcomponent() a URI-encoded piece of JSON automatically, like Firefox?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, safari, yui

I'm passing a URI-encoded JSON string from secure iFrame to a non-secure grandparent iFrame.
When it reaches the parent, I parse it using YUI's

```
 YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse()
```

In Firefox, this works perfectly, and my string looks like

```
     "{\"CntctNm\":\"Mike\",
```

In Safari, it looks like

```
    "{%22CntctNm%22:%22Mike%22,
```

and

`YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse()` chokes.

So, how viable is my hackaround of looking for URI encoding, and decoding the string if I find it?

```
if(JSONstr){
  secrJsonResp.indexOf("22:%22")>-1;
  var updtJsonObj = Cmn.ParseJSON(decodeURIComponent(JSONstr));
}else{
  var updtJsonObj = Cmn.ParseJSON(JSONstr);
};
```

Comment: How are you passing the string? Why is it URI encoded?

Comment: I'm passing the string as a URL (and encoding it that way after stringifying it) because it lets the secure iFrame talk to a non-secure iFrame.

Comment: Try using [cross document messaging](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/#web-messaging) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Special characters in url in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752961/special-characters-in-url-in-safari)