# Special characters in url in Safari

Tags: safari, uri, special-characters

We are using some special characters in our web application like this: `example.com/foo#вап`.

We parse hash using `decodeURI(window.location.hash)` (and sometimes hash contains not encoded special characters) and set new value like `window.location.hash = "вап"`.

Everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and even IE, but in Safari we get `20?` instead `вап`.

If set hash in Safari like `window.location.hash = encodeURI("вап");` it works, but of course it doesn't work in Chrome, FF and others.

Comment: I also see this same deviant behavior in Mobile Safari on iOS-6.1.6 (iPod) and iOS-7.1.1 (iPad).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. 
If set hash through `window.location.href` everything works fine.

Here is the code:

```
var newHash = ...
var sharpIdx = window.location.href.indexOf("#");
if (sharpIdx === -1) {
  window.location.href = window.location.href + "#" + newHash;
} else {
  window.location.href = window.location.href.substr(0, sharpIdx) + "#" + newHash;
}
```

Comment: So not only is accessing `location.href` for reading the fragment more reliable than reading `location.hash` (because Mozilla handles reading `location.hash` wrong), but writing to it for hash updates is more reliable because of Safari. Good to know. This is an easier-to-code solution than fixing my code to call `encodeURIComponent()` on the right pieces before assigning it to `location.hash`…

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue, found another workaround

```
window.location.hash = path;
// For safari url change fix
if (window.location.hash !== path) {
    window.location.hash = encodeURI(path);
}
```